# Finding all the binary bit strings of a given length

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica, this forum and programming in general.

I m trying to fulfill a given task. I want to write a function, which takes as input an positive integer, say $n$, and returns a table of all possible bit strings of length $n$. So, for example, `f[3]` should return

> `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, ..., {1, 1, 1}}`

If anyone could help me I'd be grateful.

Comment: Somehow it cut of the beginning of my post. There is a "Hello together" missing :D

Answer (score 5):

Take a look to `Tuples`, more specifically, try for example `Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]`.

Comment: Ja thank you very much. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You say your goal is to write a function to carry out the task you describe. Then you should consider constraining the function argument to be a positive integer. Like so,

```
bits[n_Integer?Positive] := Tuples[{0, 1}, n]
```

Then

```
bits[3]
```

> `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}`

but

```
bits[-3]
```

will not evaluate, and neither will

```
bits[3.]
```